# Movement for game character doesn't work at all

Tags: c

Here is the .c code from start to finish. I suspect it's an order of operations issue or something else.

The code is supposed to have a title screen where you can exit or play. If you hit play it renders a new char array in which you can move either left, right, or down (a/d/s). You get points for going down a row each time as well as going over 'P' spots on the array.

Once you hit y-coordinate 202 on the array as well as have positive points, you win and it renders a congrats char array. If you go negative in points (by hitting the '#' paces or the 'L' wall that goes down a row every 1/2 second) then you will lose and be told you lost in a new char array as well as be asked if you want to exit or play again.

And as mentioned before, the movement for the 'L's and the play character 'O' simply doesn't move.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char quickchar(float delay);
void render();
void titleRender();
void renderLoss();
void renderWin();
int score();

char titlescreen[20][59] = { };
char diffdiff[20][46] = {
    (Grid removed due to char limit)                       
};
char gameover[20][50] = {
    (Grid removed due to char limit)                        
};
char gameboard[203][26] = {
    (Grid removed due to char limit)
};

int playerx;
int playery;
int pts;

void entryRender();
void gameRender();

int main() {
    int input;
    char replay;
    int lx;
    int ly;
    char walkin;
    int gaming;
    char titlechoice;
    int diff;
    int running;

    lx = 0;
    ly = 0;
    running = 1;
    playerx = 13;
    playery = 5;
    pts = 25;
    gaming = 0;

    while (gaming == 0) {
        titleRender();
        printf("\033[1;32m");
        printf("\nPress 'p' to play or 'x' to exit!");
        printf("\033[0m");
        scanf(" %c", &titlechoice);
                
        if (titlechoice == 'p') {
            gaming += 4;
        }

        if (titlechoice == 'x') {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    while (gaming == 4) {
        system("stty -echo raw");
        render();
        printf("\033[1;35m");
        printf("Choose a direction: s/Down, a/Left, d/Right.\n\r");
        printf("\033[0m");
        walkin = quickchar(0.5);
        scanf("%c", &walkin);
        //obj behaviour

        if (walkin == 's' && 
            gameboard[playery +1][playerx] != '#' && 
            gameboard[playery + 1][playerx] != '+' && 
            gameboard[playery + 1][playerx] != '|' &&                                                                              
            gameboard[playery + 1][playerx] != '-') { 
            playery++;
            pts += 5;

            if (gameboard[playery + 1][playerx] == '#') {
                pts -= 25;
            }

            if (gameboard[playery + 1][playerx] == 'P') {
                printf("Points increased!\n\r");
                pts += 50;
                gameboard[playery + 1][playerx] = '_';
            }
        }
        else if (walkin == 'a' && 
                 gameboard[playery][playerx - 1] != '#' && 
                 gameboard[playery][playerx - 1] != '+' && 
                 gameboard[playery][playerx - 1] != '|' && 
                 gameboard[playery][playerx - 1] != '-') {
            playerx--;
            
            if (gameboard[playery][playerx - 1] == '#') {
                pts -= 25;
            }

            if (gameboard[playery][playerx - 1] == 'P') {
                printf("Points increased!\n\r");
                pts += 50;
                gameboard[playery][playerx - 1] = '_';
            }
        } 
        else if (walkin == 'd' && 
                 gameboard[playery][playerx + 1] != '#' && 
                 gameboard[playery][playerx + 1] != '+' &&
                 gameboard[playery][playerx + 1] != '|' &&
                 gameboard[playery][playerx + 1] != '-') {
             playerx++;
             
             if (gameboard[playery][playerx + 1] == '#') {
                 pts -= 25;
             }

             if (gameboard[playery + 1][playerx] == 'P) {
                 printf("Points increased!\n\r");
                 pts += 50;
                 gameboard[playery][playerx + 1] = '_';
             }
         }
             
         if (walkin == 'a' || walkin == 's' || walkin == 'd' || 
             walkin != 'a' || walkin != ' ' || walkin != 'd' ) {
             for (ly = 0; ly = 202; ly++) {
                 for (lx = 1; lx = 25; lx++) {
                     gameboard[ly][lx] = 'L';
                 }
             }
         }
         
         if (pts <= 0) {
             system("clear");
             renderLoss();
             scanf("%c", replay);

             if (replay == 'Y') {
                 gaming = 3;
             }

             if (replay == 'N') {
                 gaming = 5;
             }
         }
         
         if (playery == 202) {
             renderWin();
             printf("");
             printf("Congrats! You got a score of %d !", pts);
             printf("");
             scanf("%c", &replay);
                                
             if (replay == 'Y') {
                 gaming = 4;
             }

             if (replay == 'N') {
                 gaming = 5;
             }
         }
                
         //player postion == 203y, then congrta screen
         //ask player to set gaming to 4(replay) or none (exit program)
     }

     system("stty echo -raw");

     return 0;
 }

 void render() {
     int y,x,k;

     system("clear");
     printf("\033[01;33m");
     printf("||POINTS: %d||\r\n", pts);
     printf("\033[0m");

     for (y = 0; y < 203; y++) {
         for (x = 0; x < 26; x++) {
             if (y == playery && x == playerx) {
                 printf("\033[0;32m");
                 printf("O");
                 printf("\033[0m");
             } 
             else {
                 printf("\033[1;36m");
                 printf("%c", gameboard[y][x]);
                 printf("\033[0m");
             }
         }
                
         printf("\r\n");
     }
}

void titleRender() {
    int y, x;
    system("clear");

    for (y = 0; y < 20; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < 59; x++) {
            printf("\033[0;32m");
            printf(" %c", titlescreen[y][x]);
            printf("\033[0m");
        }
            
        printf("\r\n");
    }
}

void renderLoss() {
    int y, x;
    system("clear");
    
    for (y = 0; y < 26; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < 50; x++) {
            printf("\033[0;31m");
            printf(" %c", gameover[y][x]);
            printf("\033[0m");
        }
        
        printf("\r\n");
    }
}

void renderWin() {
    int y, x;
    system("clear");
    
    for (y = 0; y < 20; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < 46; x++) {
            printf("\033[0;33m");
            printf(" %c", diffdiff);
            printf("\033[0m");
        }
        
        printf("\r\n");
    }
}

char quickchar(float delay) {
    int flags;
    char c;

    usleep((int)(delay*1000000));

    flags = fcntl(0, F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(0, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
    c = getchar();
    fcntl(0, F_SETFL, flags ^ O_NONBLOCK);

    return c;
}
```

Comment: Step 1 is to write a very simple test program that allows you to move the player's character 'O' on the screen. There's no point in writing a whole bunch of code if you don't have the basic technology mastered.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).